# Get Device Interface ID

Tags: interface, device

I'm working on a project according to this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540174(v=vs.85).aspx

One of the Prerequisites is to install a driver with a generated (I think) Device Interface id, but what if instead of installing a new driver I want to work with an existing one. How/where can I check the Device Interface id for an usb device for example?